# _.each performance issue - Underscorejs

Tags: underscore.js

Object array contains 700 objects. I have used underscore _.each for calculation to get the average. The code is working fine but there is a huge lag time for calculation. Please refer the below code and advise me.

```
typesOverall=
Analytics:{[{
Analytics:{
area:"Digital"
category:"Analytics"
qId:"iBWmASYL6HQMtpzGH"
type:"Reinvent"
userId:"2PXk3uJqKrWeJW3RW"
val:1.333333333333333
},
{
Analytics:{
area:"Digital"
category:"Analytics"
qId:"iBWmASYL6HQMtpzGH"
type:"Reinvent"
userId:"2PXk3uJqKrWeJW3RW"
val:1.333333333333333
}...........]}

_.each(typesOverall, function(val, key) {
          result[key] = _.reduce(val, function(memo, v) {
            return memo + v.val;
          }, 0) / val.length * 10;
      });
```

Comment: Could you include what `typesOverall` looks like in your question?

Comment: @Tholle - I have edited my question again. Could you please refer it

Answer (score 1):

here is the code that underscore uses to implement the `_.each` functionality,

```
// The cornerstone, an `each` implementation, aka `forEach`.
// Handles raw objects in addition to array-likes. Treats all
// sparse array-likes as if they were dense.

_.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
  iteratee = optimizeCb(iteratee, context);
  var i, length;
  if (isArrayLike(obj)) {
    for (i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
      iteratee(obj[i], i, obj);
    }
  } else {
    var keys = _.keys(obj);
    for (i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
      iteratee(obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj);
    }
  }
  return obj;
};
```

> As it's clear that they created this function's for quick using purposes. It can be use in any simpler data or where performance is not a great issue.
>
> But, experts always encourage that if you can implement your own `each` function to optimise the calculation.
>
> Another important thing is that if you are much concern about your `code performance` then you might consider to change your `data architecture` and implement optimized code as much as possible.
>
> And when it's come to the optimized code implementation you might need to have a good knowledge of Big(O) notation that is Best, worst and average case scenario.